# Huge matrix in my document. Possible ways to make it look better?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

The following is the source for a matrix I'm using in my document:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{19}

\begin{document}
\[\begin{pmatrix}
1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& & & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_1 & \alpha & & & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_2 & \beta_1 & & & & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
& \beta_2 & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_3 & & \alpha & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_4 & & \beta_3 & & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & & &\\
& & \beta_4 & & & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_5 & & & \alpha & & & & & & & 1 & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_6 & & & \beta_5 & & & & & & & & 1 & & & & & & &\\
& & & \beta_6 & & & & & & & & & 1 & & & & & &\\
\beta_7 & \alpha & & & & & & & & & & & & 1 & & & & &\\
\beta_8 & \beta_7 & & & & & & & & & & & & & 1 & & & &\\
\beta_9 & & \beta_8 & & & & & & & & & & & & & 1 & & &\\
\beta_{10} & & \beta_9 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & 1 & &\\
\beta_{11} & & & \beta_{10} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & 1 &\\
& & & \beta_{11} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & 1
\end{pmatrix}\]
\end{document}
```

The output looks very strange since the first four colums are wider than the last. But I guess I can't fix that, because otherwise the matrix would be too wide. Do you have any idea on what I could do to make the matrix look 'better'? Any suggestions are welcome. I have already thought of splitting the matrix up and only specifying the important 15x4 part.

[image: Output]

Comment: `[utf8]` is not an option to `fontenc`, edited

Comment: Maybe a sum of the important part + eye(19)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to my belief that no array using `\multirow` can't be improved by removing it, here's a simpler variation to percusse's answer:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % not necessary for the example
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
\\
\mbox{\Huge$I$} & \makebox[12em]{\Huge$0$} \\
\\
\hline
\begin{matrix}
\beta_1 & \alpha \\
\beta_2 & \beta_1 \\
& \beta_2 \\
\beta_3 & & \alpha \\
\beta_4 & & \beta_3 \\
& & \beta_4 \\
\beta_5 & & & \alpha \\
\beta_6 & & & \beta_5 \\
& & & \beta_6 \\
\beta_7 & \alpha \\
\beta_8 & \beta_7 \\
\beta_9 & & \beta_8 \\
\beta_{10} & & \beta_9 \\
\beta_{11} & & & \beta_{10} \\
& & & \beta_{11} \\
\end{matrix} & \mbox{\Huge$I$}
\end{array}\right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be nicer if the identity matrices had the dimensions: I_{4}, I_{15}.

Comment: @suvayu It's easy to add them and you're probably right.

Answer (score 22):

You can remove the identity elements and replace with `I`.I forgot to put `I_{4\times 4}` and similarly 15 but you can add it directly.

Still too big but at least it's consistent. I would really go a low rank representation of that 4 column nonzero part and make it a variable.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,multirow}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{19}

\begin{document}
\[\left(
\begin{array}{cccc|ccccccccccccccc}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\multirow{4}[2]{*}{\Huge $I$}}&%
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\multirow{4}[2]{*}{\Huge$0$}}\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
\beta_1 & \alpha  &         &         &%
\multicolumn{15}{c}{\multirow{15}[2]{*}{\Huge$I$}}\\
\beta_2 & \beta_1 &         &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        & \beta_2 &         &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_3 &         & \alpha  &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_4 &         & \beta_3 &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        &         & \beta_4 &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_5 &         &         & \alpha  & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_6 &         &         & \beta_5 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        &         &         & \beta_6 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_7 & \alpha  &         &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_8 & \beta_7 &         &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_9 &         & \beta_8 &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_{10} &      & \beta_9 &         & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
\beta_{11} &      &         & \beta_{10} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
        &         &         & \beta_{11} & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & 
\end{array}\right)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please do what @egreg says. Next time I'll wait a few years to make sure that he doesn't write an answer.

Answer (score 12):

I'd tempted to write

```
\[
\left(
  \begin{array}{@{} c | c @{}}
    1_{4} & 0_{4} \\
    \hline
    A &  1_{15}
  \end{array}
\right)
\]
```

where ...

In general these very large matrices are very hard for the readers to understand and keep track of. If like in this case, it can easily be split into blocks, then that would help readability.

Answer (score 10):

Although I agree with the answers which try to group in blocks the different parts of the matrix (such as Percusse's or egreg's answers), I'll provide an example which uses TikZ to draw a matrix more similar to the original one.

Using a `matrix of math nodes`, it is possible to ensure that each node (cell) has the same dimensions, and thus have all of them evenly spaced:

```
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, column sep=0mm, 
   minimum width=4.5ex,  % Of each cell
   name=M, nodes in empty cells,
   left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] {
  %% Exactly the same rows of the original code, copy&pasted here
  %% with \\ added in the last line
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Now, being a tikz picture it is possible to draw lines which help to read the matrix. Each cell in the matrix is a tikz node which has a name automatically assigned, as `M-y-x` being `y` the row number and `x` the column number.

## Update: debugging the figure

@Thomas noted in a comment that the line of `1`s didn't look straight. I was unable to notice it, so I added the option `nodes=draw` to the matrix options. This was the result:

[image: Debug]

Now it is clearly visible that there are small horizontal gaps between some boxes, apparently due to the elements `\beta_{10}` and `\beta_{11}` beingh slightly larger than the minimum width used of 4.5ex. And, more important, not all cells have the same height, and this produces different distance between the rows. It is clearly noticeable that the first three rows have no vertical gaps between boxes, while the others have. (Incidentally I also discovered that two rows had the last cell missing).

So, enlarging a bit the minimum width and giving also a minimum height, the following result can be achieved:

[image: Good]

The above figure was produced by the following code (I grouped all node specific options into `nodes` keyword):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, column sep=0mm, 
  nodes = {minimum height=3.6ex,
           minimum width=4.7ex, anchor=center, draw
           }, 
   name=M, nodes in empty cells,
   left delimiter=(, right delimiter=)] {
      %% The same rows of the original code, copy&pasted here and fixed
      %% with \\ added in the last line
   };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Just to test your eyesight, there is the same figure without `draw` option:

[image: Is this ok?]

Comment: It still looks bent though. Must be an optical illusion caused by the other entries.

Comment: @Thomas Answer updated.

Answer (score 8):

Here's an attempt. First step, replace pmatrix with array so you can insert rules. 
Then we make the first few cols equal-spaced by putting in phantom elements equal in width to the widest thing appearing, beta_11.

Since the right-hand side of your matrix is essentially a rectangular block of zeroes above a unit submatrix, I refer to them as such and delineate them with horizontal/vertical rules. You can choose other symbols to refer to the unit matrix like a math-blackboard font 1 if you like, or use 1s in the top left and botom right corners and diagonal dots in between.
Adjust the length of the right-hand part as desired.

You may want to mention in the accompanying text somewhere that the matrix is square and that (whatever symbol you choose) denotes a unit submatrix.

[image]

```
\[
\left(\begin{array}{lllll|c}
1 & \phantom{\beta_{11}} & \phantom{\beta_{11}} & \phantom{\beta_{11}} & \\
& 1 & & & \\ 
& & 1 & & & \mathbf{0} \\ 
& & & 1 & \\
   \beta_1 & \alpha  &         &            & 1 & \underline{\hspace{6em}}\\
   \beta_2 & \beta_1 &         &            & \\
           & \beta_2 &         &            & \\
   \beta_3 &         & \alpha  &            & \\
   \beta_4 &         & \beta_3 &            & \\
           &         & \beta_4 &            & \\
   \beta_5 &         &         & \alpha     & \\
   \beta_6 &         &         & \beta_5    & \\
           &         &         & \beta_6    & & \mathbf{1} \\
   \beta_7 &  \alpha &         &            & \\
   \beta_8 & \beta_7 &         &            & \\
   \beta_9 &         & \beta_8 &            & \\
\beta_{10} &         & \beta_9 &            & \\
\beta_{11} &         &         & \beta_{10} & \\
           &         &         & \beta_{11} & \\
\end{array}\right) 
\]
```

Comment: Oops, "off by one" - the fifth column is redundant and should probably be deleted.

Comment: It would be more usual to write the lower right block as I (identity matrix) instead of 1, which sometimes denotes a matrix of all ones.